# what's the right way to periodically query the database and upload data to external web service?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a Windows Forms application which collects data from multiple devices - and stores that data in the local SQLite database. Then, with a certain period, I need to upload new records to external webservice - meaning I need to read new records with "WasUploaded = 0" field, upload them, and then set "WasUploaded = 1" on success. Today I would do this the same way I would do it 10 years ago - fork a new background thread, and do endless cycle:

```
while(true) 
{
   try
   {
        var newRecords = dbRepo.ReadNew(10);    // read 10 records at a time
        UploadToExternalWebservice(newRecords);
        foreach (var r in newRecords)
        {
            r.WasUploaded = 1;
        }
        dbRepo.CommitChanges(newRecords);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex);
    }

    Thread.Current.Sleep(15*1000);
}
```

but I started to wonder - is there a better way to do this may be? Is it worth using Tasks library here?.. something else?

I'm on .Net 4.0 if that matters.

Thank you.

Comment: As long as you're comfortable with the background thread as far as synchronizing and safety I'd just go for what you already know. Anything else out there will basically just be an abstraction on top of this anyway, and especially if you've written the code already you wouldn't really be gaining anything. If you have perf problems or concerns that might be another reason to try something different, however.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: But why suffer the overhead of an additional thread when it spends most of its time sleeping? Seems easier to leverage the built-in timer that does exactly what is needed, and take advantage of the threadpool that's built just for this kind of thing. In addition, the timer can be stopped at any time. You can't safely stop a thread externally. In general, a thread that does a sleep loop is almost always a sloppy and inefficient way to simulate a periodic timer.

Comment: How much overhead does a single sleeping thread have?  What I don't like about a timer is that it runs every `X` seconds regardless of the task completing unless you write logic (as you showed) to handle it. The threaded route takes 1ms or 5 hours to run, sleeps and repeats, no need to even be concerned about possible concurrent runs. As for stopping, that's why I put in there if the OP is already comfortable with the paradigm, stopping another thread that you've launched is relatively easy.

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer. Set it for every 10 minutes (or whatever), and do the upload then.

```
System.Threading.Timer uploadTimer = new Timer(UploadProc, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));

void UploadProc(object state)
{
    // do query, upload, and update logic here
}
```

There's no need for an explicit thread that spends most of its time sleeping.

If you want it to be more frequent (you have 15 seconds in your example), you run into the possibility of re-entrant timer ticks. That is, if you have it set for 15 seconds and it takes more than 15 seconds to do the processing, you'll end up with multiple threads running the upload code concurrently.

If that's a possibility, you have two choices: use a lock to prevent the re-entrancy, or use a one-shot timer that you update after every process.

The lock is pretty easy. Define a lock object at class scope:

```
private object uploadLock = new object();
```

And inside the UploadProc:

```
void UploadProc(object state)
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(uploadLock))
    {
        // upload in progress. Quit.
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        // processing here
    } 
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(uploadLock);
    }
}
```

That works well. The one-shot idea involves setting the timer to tick once and then stop. You then update it after you're done processing:

```
System.Threading.Timer uploadTimer = new Timer(
    UploadProc, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));

void UploadProc(object state)
{
    // processing here
    // now reset the timer
    uploadTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic push vs pull problem. If the datasource can notify you, you can do it then, but otherwise I think your approach is the correct one. You can set up different service that pulls these data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quartz to set a job to to that periodically, using a Timer is definitively not the best way to do that, you can, but that is a quick dirt way of doing it.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

And you could also use a queue for your jobs.

Comment: Wondering why you'd add Quartz to your application just to implement a simple timer task. Seems like overkill.

Comment: Maybe, but it allows you to use cron expressions which adds a great degree of accuracy apart from that it is a proper job scheduling system.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `DispatcherTimer` class for this.

Example usage:

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
dt.Tick += delegate(object s, EventArgs args) {

//Your Logic here!!    

};
timer.Start();
```

And also here is the class: [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure you want a database update to run on the UI thread? Also, I don't think `DispatcherTimer` works in Windows Forms apps.

Comment: Well DispatcherTimer is there for to call an update function from ViewModel which also calls an Update function in web service?